# Capifony: update vendors and deps file

Tags: symfony, capistrano, capifony

Is it possible to setup deployment script so that vendors would only update if deps file has changed since the last update?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I struggled with the same problem one week ago and I found the solution.
The file symfony2.rb (at my server located under /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capifony-2.1.4/lib) has the following ruby-code at the very end:

```
case vendors_mode
  when "upgrade" then symfony.vendors.upgrade
  when "install" then symfony.vendors.install
  when "reinstall" then symfony.vendors.reinstall
end
```

Also at the very top of the same file you can see the default value for vendors_mode:

```
set :vendors_mode, "reinstall"
```

Now in my deploy.rb I used the following:

```
set :vendors_mode, "install"
```

With this setting vendors are only installed if they don't exist yet in the target-version of the deps-file!

Comment: Note that `:vendors_mode` is ignored if you use composer, and is replaced by a complete change of meaning of `:update_vendors` https://github.com/everzet/capifony/issues/366